# Triggering Build based on commit message using Jenkins webhook trigger.

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins webhook trigger i want to trigger build only when commit message is "New Build".
Used optional filter but was not working, can someone please help.

Comment: Hi, which plugin are you using ? Are you using https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin ? Based on the plugin I can suggest how to achieve what you want

Comment: Hi,  thanks for quick reply, yeah i am using jekins genric webhook trigger.

Comment: Can you post your optional filter expression and text ? Are you using variables for Text ? If yes, also post that

Comment: In optional filter section for expression value i mentioned "New Build[^"] +? " and in text i mentioned $. commits[0].message.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `[Nn]ew.+[Bb]uild` for expression ? If the commit message has 'New Build' in it anywhere it will match. It will also match if the commit message is just New Build. Please note that this expression will also work if the commit message is 'new build' or 'New build' or 'new Build' with one or more spaces in between them.

Comment: Ben, i used what you told but build itself is not triggering when committing from git hub, when i remove everything from optional filter its triggering build but without any filter as i removed. Not sure why its not at all running job when i commit from git hub using optional filter.

Comment: Ben, its working now i missed $ in text field, my bad.. Thanks for help.

Comment: working now with the expression I suggested ? Or working now because you originally missed $ in text field ?

Comment: Its working with your expression only..!!!

Comment: Cheers. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple pattern `[Nn]ew.+[Bb]uild` for expression. If the commit message has 'New Build' in it anywhere it will match. It will also match if the commit message is just New Build. Please note that this expression will also work if the commit message is 'new build' or 'New build' or 'new Build' with one or more spaces in between them

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any (working) way to do a conditional trigger with WebHooks, however you can access the change sets via the `currentBuild` as described [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-) and only perform specific steps only if the message is "New Build":

```
def latestChangeSet = currentBuild.changeSet.items[-1]
if (latestChangeSet.msg != "New Build") {
    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS' // this will prevent the build from being marked failed
    return // this will exit the pipeline
}
```

If you are interested in further details about the build, check the [`Build` class doc](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Build.html).